# Convert netcdf file to tiff (with spatial referencing information preserved)

Tags: coordinate-system, netcdf, envi, geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate

I was trying to convert a netcdf file (~5 GB in size) to a tiff format using both Gdal_translate and ENVI. Was successful in ENVI but I'm missing spatial information. Using gdal_translate (gdal_translate - sds file.nc file.tiff), it looks like file is too heavy as it's taking long. I used QGIS too but there was a slight spatial shift in the two images.

I've checked similar past Q/Q but none seems to give me a solution. Any better idea out there?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use R? I'd do these steps...

```
library(raster)

# read the netcdf file as raster
nc_raster = raster("input_file.nc")

# if raster crs is NA, set the correct projection using proj4
projection(nc_raster) = CRS(+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0)

# save output
writeRaster(nc_raster, "nc_raster.tif", "GTiff")
```

The most important is to know the correct proj4 format, otherwise the data will be shifted.